# Set the value of one column based on values in other rows of a database table

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
| Date       | Name | Activity |
+------------+------+----------+
| 2018-01-01 | A    | 1        |
| 2018-01-01 | B    | 0        |
| 2018-01-01 | C    | 0        |
| 2018-02-01 | A    | 0        |
| 2018-02-01 | B    | 1        |
| 2018-02-01 | C    | 0        |
| 2018-03-01 | A    | 0        |
| 2018-03-01 | B    | 0        |
| 2018-03-01 | C    | 0        |
```

I need to add a column of `status` which displays as active or inactive for the name based on the value in the `activity` column.

For example:

- if in January, name A's activity is 1 then the status should be active.
- if in February name A's activity is 1 then it should show as active only but if its 0 then also it should show active as in January he was active so throughout he should be shown as active.
- we should only change the data if in the previous month's data its activity was 0 and in current month it's 1.

So, the output I'm trying to get to is:

```
| Date       | Name | Activity | Status |
+------------+------+----------+--------+
| 2018-01-01 | A    | 1        | A      |
| 2018-01-01 | B    | 0        | I      |
| 2018-01-01 | C    | 0        | I      |
| 2018-02-01 | A    | 0        | A      |
| 2018-02-01 | B    | 1        | A      |
| 2018-02-01 | C    | 0        | I      |
| 2018-03-01 | A    | 0        | A      |
| 2018-03-01 | B    | 0        | A      |
| 2018-03-01 | C    | 0        | I      |
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately in its current state your question is hard to read and to understand what the problem is you're asking about. Please read [ask] and [mcve] and then [edit] your question with the recommendations in those pages to help people offer answers.

Comment: I've tried to edit your question to make it more readable (you might have noticed when you read [ask] that it says "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc"). If you further edit it to include a [mcve] of the code you've tried and details of what problems you have, you'll be most of the way to a good question.

Answer (score -1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3fe040/4)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table user_activity(id int(11) not null auto_increment,
                           month date,name varchar(15),
                           activity enum('A','I'),primary key(id) );

 insert into user_activity (month,name,activity) values('2019-01-01','alpha','A');

 insert into user_activity (month,name,activity) values('2019-02-01','alpha','I');

 insert into user_activity (month,name,activity) values('2019-03-01','alpha','A');

 insert into user_activity (month,name,activity) values('2019-01-01','beta','A');

  insert into user_activity (month,name,activity) values('2019-02-01','beta','I');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from user_activity
```

**[Results][2]**:

```
| id |      month |  name | activity |
|----|------------|-------|----------|
|  1 | 2019-01-01 | alpha |        A |
|  2 | 2019-02-01 | alpha |        I |
|  3 | 2019-03-01 | alpha |        A |
|  4 | 2019-01-01 |  beta |        A |
|  5 | 2019-02-01 |  beta |        I |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select max(month),name,activity
from user_activity
where activity='A'
group by name
```

**[Results][3]**:

```
| max(month) |  name | activity |
|------------|-------|----------|
| 2019-03-01 | alpha |        A |
| 2019-01-01 |  beta |        A |
```

Comment: The status should be calculated based on activity not added manually

Comment: share the create and insert query for the output

Comment: and share how the output should look like.

Comment: is there a way to write this in stored procedures?

Comment: So, is that the output after the edit, is what you want?

Comment: Yes the output should be compared with previous month and then update the status.